# How to get image from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to access image from database direct in razor view.

This is my code

```
@model IEnumerable<TelerikMvcAppCombo.Models.ImageModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}


@foreach (var image in Model)
{ 
    <img src=@image.IMAGESIZE_DESC/>
}
```

This is my model Class:-

```
[Table("IMAGESIZE")]
public class ImageModel
{
    [Key]
    public int IMAGESIZE_ID { get; set; }
    public string IMAGESIZE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string IMAGESIZE_DESC { get; set; }
    public int created_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
    public int modified_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Controller Class:-

```
public JsonResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var list = db.imageModels.ToList();
    return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to access Image or Image Url ?

Comment: basically <img src tag is take url and display image. but if i directly bind url to src with model then is not working? image is not displaying why?

Comment: and here the description property is for url tag for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's your problem exactly but try this:

```
@foreach (var image in Model)
{ 
    <img src="@Url.Content(image.IMAGESIZE_DESC)" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your view name but I assume that It is GetData.
You have to return ViewResult instead of JsonResult. You are returning JsonResult so it is not working.

```
public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var list = db.imageModels.ToList();
    return View(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

If you want to use JsonResult then you have to get data client side and bind them client side and in that case Razor view is not working.

Comment: but i m using telerik kendo thats why i am using Json here

Comment: Please mention that and Also I don't see that in your code part. Please update your sample.